# Jquery | Display a div while typing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Could you please help me to complete my current code. first I managed to display, fade in and out the div but for some reason, it keeps coming and going!! once I start typing I get what I want but it repeats the fades regardless of me doing anything.

second I want to have the div to be displayed beside my text area having a nice css format.

here is my script :

```
$(function() {
var moveLeft = -200;
var moveDown = -210;
  $("#quickSMScustomMessage").keyup(
function(){

  $('div#pop-up').fadeIn(200).show().delay(2000).fadeOut(1000);
  //.css('top', e.pageY + moveDown)
  //.css('left', e.pageX + moveLeft)
  //.appendTo('body');

});

});
```

Comment: can you post a bit more code with html elements as well?

Comment: this is my html div to be displayed

Comment: <div id="pop-up">
   <span id="previewText" class="txtPrev" style="font-size: 8pt;   text-align:left;float:left; line-height:8px white-space: nowrap; padding-left: 6px;"></span>
 </div>

Answer (score 0):

Just add stop to stop all previous animations... or they will queue

```
$('div#pop-up').stop().fadeIn()...
```

Comment: you mean this:       
$('div#pop-up').stop().fadeIn(200).show().delay(2000).fadeOut(1000); ?? 
I did and does not display the div at all. stopped working

Comment: there must be a way to stop this recursion!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another suggestion... use timeout to do it...

```
    var timer;    
    $('#type').keyup(function(){
        clearTimeout(timer);
        $('#typeHelper').stop().fadeIn(200);
        timer = setTimeout(function(){
            $('#typeHelper').fadeOut(1000)            
        },2000)
    })
```

[TRY DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qLxVh/)